# How to INSERT using SELECT on Table and Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem in Access to UPDATE based on a JOIN.

There are 2 Statement which I need to merge:

```
SELECT a.f1, a.f2, a.f3
  FROM tableA a, viewB b
  WHERE a.f2 = b.f2 AND a.f3 = b.f3
```

viewB is a query, but works fine

```
UPDATE tableA a
  SET a.f1 = 'x'
```

works fine, too.

Now I try:

```
UPDATE tableA a, viewB b
  SET a.f1 = 'x'
  WHERE a.f2 = b.f2 AND a.f3 = b.f3
```

Fails, Access says:

> Operation must use an updateable query.

This is stupid, because there is no field touched in viewB.
I tried several other solutions with FROM, JOIN Subselect, but did not found a solution.

Does anybody know a smart solution on that?

Answer (score 5):

Try the `update .. join` syntax:

```
update tableA a
inner join viewB b on a.f2 = b.f2 and a.f3 = b.f3
set a.f1 = 'x'
```

Or alternatively:

```
update tableA a
set a.f1 = 'x'
where exists (select * from viewB b where a.f2 = b.f2 and a.f3 = b.f3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the join syntax, not the where syntax in order to join the tables:

```
UPDATE tableA AS a 
INNER JOIN viewB AS b
    ON (a.f2 = b.f2) AND (a.f3 = b.f3)
SET a.f1 = 'x';
```

Also note that it will only work, if `viewB` is updatable. If `viewB` has a GROUP BY or a UNION, for instance, it will not be updatable.

---

EDIT: If `viewB` is not updatable a subquery instead of a join will help:

```
UPDATE tableA AS a
SET a.f1 = 'x'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM viewB AS b
              WHERE (a.f2=b.f2) AND (a.f3=b.f3))
```

Comment: Olivier, thank you. Exactly this is the problem. viewB is NOT updateable because it uses DISTINCT - but if you look at my code, I do not want to update anything of viewB, but I need it to find my records for update. Any idea?

Comment: In this case, you can use a subquery (as Andomar has already proposed): `UPDATE tableA AS a SET a.f1 = 'x' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM viewB AS b WHERE (a.f2=b.f2) AND (a.f3=b.f3))`. See my edit.

Comment: No, it does not work: The subquery works correct but the UPDATE operates on ALL records: It seems to me that the upper query and the subquery are not connected correctly.

Comment: There are different primary keys in tableA and viewB: viewB does not have a PK.

Comment: It will update every record in tableA which has a corresponding record in viewB for which `tableA.f2=viewB.f2 AND tableA.f3=viewB.f3` is true.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give permissions. remove read only from that folder or mdb file so that it will allow to update  check this link.

[Operation must use an updateable query. (Microsoft JET Database Engine)](http://support.yessoftware.com/kb_article.asp?article_id=72)

[ASp.net forum thread for : opreation must use an updateble query](http://forums.asp.net/t/141946.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableA
  SET a.f1 = 'x'
  from  tableA a, viewB b
  WHERE a.f2 = b.f2 AND a.f3 = b.f3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when Access says you're not creating an updateable query, it responds to setting the query's 'unique records' property to 'yes.'